# Core Data, Concurrency and GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm having difficulties trying to figure out how to use Core Data concurrently and properly.

I have to clear Core Data of an entity before adding new data every time there is an update. Therefore I've decided to use this snippet:

```
-(void)addSale:(NSArray *)results{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSString *entity = @"Sale";

    CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [CoreDataManager.sharedInstance deleteEntityWithName:entity];
    });

    NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    privateContext.parentContext = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext;

    for (NSDictionary *dataDictionary in [results valueForKey:@"Sales"])
    {
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entity inManagedObjectContext:privateContext];


        // Fill ManagedObject
        // .....

    }

    NSError *error;
    [privateContext save:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save private context bcoz of %@\n%@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Save Main ManagedObjectContext
        [CoreDataManager.sharedInstance saveContext:CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext WithEntityName:entity];
    });
});
}
```

Problem is that I have to do the same thing for 2 other entities while keeping the UI responsive without having any impacts on the Core Data.

Is there any better approaches to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a private context associated with the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.
2. Delete objects in the private context.
3. Save private context.
4. Tell main queue context to reset if any of those objects were being used.

There really is no reason to delete objects on the main context (which it appears you are doing with your singleton).

If your UI has not touched any of the objects you are deleting then you do not need to reset the context associated with the User Interface.

You could also, instead of doing a reset, have the main queue context consume the save notification from the private queue context and that will net the same result.